# Vuejs passing props to from parents component to child component not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parameter-passing, vue-devtools

I am newbie and in charge a project using Vuejs.

Here is a page that use a component called DashboardCard and each DardboardCard is passed 2 props is val and icon from the page a.k.a the parent component

[image: dashboard]

I declared props in DashboardCard component a.k.a child component but the value of all props can not be passed and assigned

[image: DashboardCard]

I now I got this error

[image: error]

**UPDATE**
Here is the Vuejs devtool log, you can see that props was passed
[image]

Comment: try passing it like `:icon="'@/assets/sale.png'"` and `:val="'$700'"`

Comment: Do you see icon property in the Vue devtools? or have you tried to log it out?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or sandbox with your code?

Comment: @Amaarrockz it would make no difference

Comment: @Amaarrockz you can try this https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-meadow-5zuee?file=/src/components/DashboardCard.vue

Comment: @TâmĐỗ nhìn tên tưởng người quen =))

Answer (score 2):

The reason, is that before even the props hold the value, you are trying to access it. So there are two ways I would suggest

From parent component (**Dashboard.vue**):

Try passing it like `:icon="'@/assets/sale.png'"` and `:val="'$700'"`

and in child Component (**DashboardCard.vue**)

***Method-1:***

Declare two data variables and set them with the prop values using watch handler

```
export default {
 components: {DatePicker},
 props: {
   icon: {
     type: String,
     default: ''
   },
   val: {
     type: String,
     default: ''
   }
 },
 data() {
  return {
    iconPath: '',
    amtVal: ''
  };
 },
 watch: {
  icon(newVal, oldVal) {
    this.iconPath = newVal;
  },
  val(newVal, oldVal) {
    this.amtVal = newVal;
  }
 }
```

and in template use your local data variables like

```
<span>{{amtVal}}</span>

and

<img :src="require(iconPath)" alt="icon" />
```

***Method-2:***

Using a computed property

```
export default {
 components: {DatePicker},
 props: {
   icon: {
     type: String,
     default: ''
   },
   val: {
     type: String,
     default: ''
   }
 },
 computed: {
   getIcon() {
     return this.icon;
   },
   getVal() {
    return this.val;
   }
 }
```

and in template

```
<span>{{getVal}}</span>

and

<img :src="require(getIcon)" alt="icon" />
```

Comment: I tried both 2 ways, nothing happened with same error as the very beginning, could you kindly modify this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-meadow-5zuee?file=/src/components/DashboardCard.vue

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `script` ending tag `</script>` in the `DashboardCard` component so Vue can't spot out the component properties. At first, I thought there was more code down there until I try the sandbox.

Please note that in the Vue devtools extension, a prop is supposed to sit under the `props` tab, which is not your case.

I suggest you using some kind of snippets to avoid this annoying typos. For me I use `Vetur`. It also helps with syntax highlighting, pretty handy extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur